# Using Aria to make a div table accessible

Tags: html, wai-aria

**Context:** I have a div table that a client wants to be screen reader accessible like a  regular html table is using the table commands

**Problem:** Cant get aria to work to announce the header with the row value to keep the integrity intact with the data.

**Solutions:** Only using div is it possible to make this accessible?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    .Table
    {
        display: table;
    }
    .Title
    {
        display: table-caption;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: larger;
    }
    .Heading
    {
        display: table-row;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .Row
    {
        display: table-row;
    }
    .Cell
    {
        display: table-cell;
        border: solid;
        border-width: thin;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
</style>
<title>Div Table Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="Table" role = "grid" aria-readonly="true">
    <div class="Title">
        <p>Example</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Heading" role = "columnheader">
        <div class="Cell">
            <p>Name</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell" role = "columnheader">
            <p>Symbol</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell" role = "columnheader">
            <p>Quantity</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Row" role = "row">
        <div class="Cell" role = "gridcell">
            <p>Bank of America corp</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell" role = "gridcell">
            <p>BAC</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell" role = "gridcell">
            <p>139.00</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Row" role = "row"">
        <div class="Cell" role = "gridcell">
            <p>Ebay Inc</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell" role = "gridcell">
            <p>Ebay</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell" role = "gridcell">
            <p>12.00</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>







</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's wrong with an actual table??

Comment: ^ looks tabular to me

Comment: They want it to be in divs for some reason. I advised against it but i wanted to see if there was a way around it. So much easier with a real table. The information is tabular but if you use a screen reader it will announce the headers first and then the rows but it wont re announce the header so you don't know which cell goes with which column

Comment: I'm actually creating the same thing -- I wanted to use divs for better responsive design. This Q helped me out for the answer to the accessibility part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I don't know if this will actually work considering these roles are intended for real tables. Using an actual table would be a much better idea.

Anyway, your roles could be improved.

Looks like your `columnheader` context is wrong. The header row should use the `row` `role`:

```
<div class="Heading" role="row">
    <div class="Cell">
        <p>Name</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Cell" role="columnheader">
        <p>Symbol</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Cell" role="columnheader">
        <p>Quantity</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

See: http://rawgit.com/w3c/aria/master/aria/aria.html#columnheader

Also, if this 'table' is not interactive you should use `role="table"`, not `role="grid"`. See note: http://rawgit.com/w3c/aria/master/aria/aria.html#grid

If the reason for the 'div table' is that you need a responsive table, see: https://css-tricks.com/responsive-data-tables/

Comment: Thank you! Works exactly like a table now

Comment: I don't think there is a role="table". We can use aria-readonly="true" in this case.

Comment: There is a `role="table"`, and according to MDN, `aria-roles` _are_ meant for any element. In fact their examples use nothing but `div` elements as tables: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/table_role. In any case, they still state "Using a native HTML `<table>` element whenever possible is strongly encouraged".

Answer (score 0):

I've added ARIA attributes to the code so screen reader could read it properly.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    .Table
    {
        display: table;
    }
    .Title
    {
        display: table-caption;
        text-align: center;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: larger;
    }
    .Heading
    {
        display: table-header-group;
        font-weight: bold;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .Row
    {
        display: table-row;
    }
    .Cell
    {
        display: table-cell;
        border: solid;
        border-width: thin;
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
</style>
<title>Div Table Example</title>
</head>
<body>

<div class="Table" role="grid" aria-readonly="true">
    <div class="Title">
        <p>Example</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Heading" role="row">
    <div class="Cell" role="columnheader" id="a1">
        <p>Name</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Cell" role="columnheader" id="a2">
        <p>Symbol</p>
    </div>
    <div class="Cell" role="columnheader" id="a3">
        <p>Quantity</p>
    </div>
</div>    <div class="Row" role="row">
        <div class="Cell" role="gridcell" aria-labelledby="a1">
            <p>Bank of America corp</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell" role="gridcell" aria-labelledby="a2">
            <p>BAC</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell" role="gridcell" aria-labelledby="a3">
            <p>139.00</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="Row" role="row">
        <div class="Cell" role="gridcell" aria-labelledby="a1">
            <p>Ebay Inc</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell" role="gridcell" aria-labelledby="a2">
            <p>Ebay</p>
        </div>
        <div class="Cell" role="gridcell" aria-labelledby="a3">
            <p>12.00</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```